# How can I filter nested lists in java

Tags: java, list, filter, nested, stream

I have list of Recipes and List of Alergens from user and I need to return List of Recipes in with products there is not any alergen from alergensOfUser list.

Each Recipe contains list of Products and each Product contains list of Alergens. How can I do it?

```
public class Recipe {

    ...

    private List<Product> products;

}


public class Product {
   
    ...

    private List<Alergen> alergens;

}
```

Comment: Please share your attempt and explain what obstacles have you faced - what fail, what error-messages you're getting, what's the input you're passing. Don't post a just a bear problem statement - see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java streams.
What we need to get is if recipe is made of products for which each of the product has no alergen in user's defined alergen.

```
List<Recipe> recipesList;
List<Alergen> userAllergens;

public List<Recipe> getRecipesForUser() {
    return recipesList.stream()
            .filter(recipe -> isNotMadeOfAlergen(recipe))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public boolean isNotMadeOfAlergen(Recipe recipe) {
    List<Product> productList = recipe.products;

    return productList.stream().noneMatch(product -> containsAlergen(product));
}

public boolean containsAlergen(Product product) {
    List<Alergen> alergenList = product.alergens;

    return alergenList.stream()
            .anyMatch(alergen -> userAllergens.contains(alergen));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid 3 levels of nested streams, you can do this

```
  List<Recipe> userEnteredRecipes; //populate it
  List<Alergen> userEnteredAlergens; //populate it
  List<Product> allProducts; //populate it

  // first get products which have these alergens
  List<Product> productsToAvoid =
      allProducts.stream()
          .filter(e -> e.getAlergens().stream().anyMatch(userEnteredAlergens::contains))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

  // get the recipes which do not have these alergens
  List<Recipe> filteredRecipes =
      userEnteredRecipes.stream()
          .filter(e -> (e.getProducts().stream().noneMatch(productsToAvoid::contains)))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```